# Sleep() does not give accurate representation of time

Tags: c++

I created a simple timer program as follows.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    float counter = 0;
    float time = 0;
    std::cin >> time;
    while (true){
        system("cls");
        std::cout << time - counter;
        Sleep(10);
        counter+= .01;
        if (time - counter < 0) break;
    }
}
```

As you can see instead of using `Clock()` I used `Sleep()`. When I have a less precise counter (`Sleep(1000); counter += 1;`) there's is not much, if any, variation from real time. However, the more precise I create the countdown the further from real time it becomes.

1. Why is that so?
2. Is there a work around if you know of one? Not a big deal though because `Clock()` works fine. This is mainly a curiosity driven question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Check what you minimum resolution is with [`timeGetDevCaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757627(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: In addition to the timing problems, you're using `float` and incrementing by 0.01. This does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

Other things happen in the loop - and that takes time. Also sleep takes at least that period of time - but it can take more.

Use sleep but adjust the time by using the clock to take these factors into account.

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your system clock, which determines when to wake up your process, is being caught in between ticks.